# Jump <location> in hexadecimal view of asmx86 homework.exe

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, hex

I probably don't understand asmx86 enough for this, so if there is an obvious answer, I'd be delighted to be presented with it. I've done a bit of googling, but nothing really comes up that says "This is your answer!" which, to be fair, probably means I'm asking the question wrong..

Working with/in/on (one of these three) the x86 intel architecture, I find that it is fairly easy to locate the jmps (of any sort) in the hexadecimal view of my practice.exe file. All the 7c, 78, 79´s etc. (link that was helpful to me:[Intelx86 http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) are starting to stand out enough to me that I can pick 'em up with little trouble.

What I can't seem to figure out is where the hex view is hiding my jmp locations.

Are they always set right after the jmp command and am I just.. I don't know, not copying or altering enough bytes to make my homework program work, or is there ever only the jmp in hex and am I not going to find a clear translation for or reference to a specific short_loc in there?

Any help, relevant links and/or references will be greatly appreciated.

(Not too sure if 'memory-management' is an accurate tag. Will remove if not related.)

Comment: What is a "jmp location"? If this is the position that the IP is moved *to* (more commonly known as "destination"), then please explain why you think it should be "right after the jmp command" - you can jump forward *or* backward in code, and by a small or a larger amount of instructions. Maybe you should post the assembly code you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking at a hex dump, be advised that not all 7C, 78, 79, etc are actually jumps, since not all are opcodes. You need to disassemble properly. As for the jump locations, relative jumps are encoded using an offset to the current address (actually the address of the next instruction). The offset is right after the opcode, but the size depends on the instruction.

As always, consult the official intel instruction set reference.

Answer (score 0):

After the opcode (and his subcodes on some instructions) of a **short jump** (conditional jumps are also short), there is **one single byte** pointing to a **relative** location. if that byte is below 128, you have to add it to the location of the jmp opcode to find the destination. Otherwise, you have to subtract the binary complement.

After the opcodes of **near jumps** there is a **absolute** location (16bit in 16bit Executables, 32bit on 32bit executables or 64bit on 64bit executables).

Comment: The __near jump__ also has a __relative encoded operand__. e.g. `jmp There`